# How to use preference fragment

Tags: android

I have the following code for preferences named settings. I want to code what happens if l click an item lets say a list dialog and select a text size. I want the text size of all activities to be changed.

settings.xml

```
    <PreferenceScreen
    android:title="SETTINGS"
    android:summary="Setrings for Text        
     Size and background colour">

    <intent
    android:targetPackage="com.ecb" 


         android:targetClass=
        "com.ecb.hymbook.Hym1"/>


    </PreferenceScreen>


    <CheckBoxPreference
    android:key="checkbox_preference"
    android:title="@string/       
    title_checkbox_preference"
    android:summary="@string/   
    summary_checkbox_preference" />

   </PreferenceCategory>

   <PreferenceCategory
    android:title="@string/     
    dialog_based_preferences">


     <ListPreference
    android:key="list_preference"
    android:title="@string/    
    title_list_preference"
    android:summary="@string/  

   summary_list_preference"
    android:entries="@array/  

     entries_list_preference"
    android:entryValues="@array/ 
    entryvalues_list_preference"
    android:dialogTitle="@string/
   dialog_title_list_preference" />

    <ListPreference
    android:key="list_preference2"
    android:title="@string/ 
    title_list_preference2"
    android:summary="@string/ 
    summary_list_preference2"
    android:entries="@array/
    entries_list_preference2"
    android:entryValues="@array/
    entryvalues_list_preference2"
    android:dialogTitle="@string/
    dialog_title_list_preference2" />

     </PreferenceCategory>

     <PreferenceCategory
      android:title="@string/   
      launch_preferences">

    <!-- This PreferenceScreen tag    
    serves as a screen break (similar to 
    page break
    in word processing). Like for other  
    preference types, we assign a key
    here so it is able to save and restore    
    its instance state. -->


    <PreferenceScreen
    android:title="@string/   
     title_intent_preference"
    android:summary="@string/
    summary_intent_preference">

    <intent 

              android:action=
    "android.intent.action.
   VIEW"
        android:data="https:// 
     chat.whatsapp.com/
    0gWQdb5idAs0fmJ0eeRaLS"/>
    </PreferenceScreen>

    </PreferenceCategory>



     </PreferenceScreen>



      Settings Java


        public class Settings
        extends Activity {

        @Override
         protected void onCreate(Bundle     
         savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate
          (savedInstanceState);

       // Display the fragment as the main    
          content.
           getFragmentManager().
           beginTransaction(  )
          .replace(android.R.id.content, new     
           PrefsFragment()).commit();




        }

        public class PrefsFragment      
         extends     
         PreferenceFragment {

        @Override
         public void onCreate(Bundle    
          savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate
         (savedInstanceState);

        // Load the preferences from an      
        XML resource
        addPreferencesFromResource
       (R.xml.settings);
       }










    }
    }



          array.xml





       <resources>
      <string-array    
      name="entries_list_preference">
      <item>DEFAULT</item>
      <item>SMALL 1</item>
       <item>SMALL 2</item>
       <item>MEDIUM 1</item>
        <item>MEDIUM 2</item>  
       <item>LARGE 1</item>
       <item>LARGE 2</item>
       <item>EXTRA LARGE 1</item>
      <item>EXTRA LARGE 2</item>
       <item>EXTREMELY LARGE</item>

       </string-array>

     <string-array name="entryvalues
      _list_preference">
    <item>DEFAULT</item>
    <item>SMALL1</item>
    <item>SMALL2</item>
    <item>MEDIUM1</item>
    <item>MEDIUM2</item>  
    <item>LARGE1</item>
    <item>LARGE2</item>
    <item>EXTRALARGE1</item>
    <item>EXTRALARGE2</item>
    <item>EXTREMELYLARGE</item> 
     </string-array>

     <string-array       
     name="entries_list_preference2">
    <item>blue</item>
    <item>brown</item>
    <item>gray</item>
    <item>violet</item>


    </string-array>

     <string-array name="entryvalues_
    list_preference2">
    <item>#ff000099</item>
    <item># 5F1E02 </item>
    <item># 333333 </item>
    <item># 421C52 </item>
    </string-array>

    </resources>
```

Comment: Have you read through [the documentation on creating a Settings page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Activity)?

Comment: Yes but im new to android development so I dont get to understand all the things. Rightnow what I need are examples

Comment: I've added an answer with a step-by-step example of creating a settings page. If there's anything you're still unsure of, do let me know. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so creating a settings page can be a little confusing at first, especially when new to Android development.

While this doesn't answer your exact question, it may give you a better understanding of how settings work in Android, so you can apply it to your own use case. Of course, if you're still unsure of something, let me know in the comments and I'll update my answer.

### Create a preferences or settings xml file

It looks like you've done this already, but I'll briefly explain it anyways.

This file determines what kind of settings are shown to the user. It goes in the `res/xml` directory. Mine looks a little like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

     <PreferenceCategory
         android:title="@string/prefCategory_general">

         <CheckBoxPreference
             android:key="pref_example_checkbox"
             android:title="@string/pref_exampleCheckbox_title"
             android:summaryOn="@string/pref_exampleCheckbox_summaryOn"
             android:summaryOff="@string/pref_exampleCheckbox_summaryOff"
             android:defaultValue="false" />
     </PreferenceCategory>

     <PreferenceCategory
         android:title="@string/prefCategory_notifications">

         <SwitchPreference
             android:key="pref_enable_notifications"
             android:title="@string/pref_notificationToggle"
             android:defaultValue="true" />

         <EditTextPreference
             android:key="pref_notification_time"
             android:title="@string/pref_notificationTime"
             android:summary="@string/pref_notificationTime_summary"
             android:inputType="number"
             android:dialogMessage="@string/pref_notificationTime_dialog"
             android:defaultValue="5" />
    </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="@string/prefCategory_about">

        <Preference
            android:key="pref_about_licenses"
            android:title="@string/pref_licenses" />

        <Preference
            android:key="pref_about_app_version"
            android:title="@string/pref_appVersion" />
    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

There are lots of different types of preferences - you can see I have checkboxes (`CheckBoxPreference`), switches (`SwitchPreference`), and also plain/standard preferences (which are basically normal list items - `Preference`). Each type of preference has different properties but they all have a `key` and `title`.

The `key` is the value your preference is stored under so this is required. They are stored on the user's device.

### Create the settings *layout* xml

Next, you need to create the activity layout for the settings page (which goes in `res/layout`.

It can be as simple or as complex as you like, but it needs to have a `FrameLayout`. Android inserts the list of settings you defined in the previous XML file into this `FrameLayout`. Here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        style="@style/Widget.MyApp.Toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Your `FrameLayout` should have an id so we can refer to it later.

### Add the activity code

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings); // your layout XML here

        // Insert the settings fragment in the FrameLayout we added earlier
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content, new SettingsFragment())
                .commit();
    }


    public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences); // the settings XML here (not the layout)
        }
    }

}
```

**Detecting preference changes:**

You can detect when the user has changed a preference by using an `OnPreferenceChangeListener`:

```
Preference preference = findPreference(key);
preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
        // Do something extra when the preference has changed.
    }
});
```

This allows you to do additional actions - but note that Android will take care of changing the preference for you (so the value for the preference key gets changed automatically).

### Reading preferences

To read preferences you need to get values from `SharedPreferences`. You can use methods like `getInt`, `getBoolean`, `getString`, etc.

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
 int preferenceValue = prefs.getInt(key, 14);
```

I usually like to put this kind of thing in a method like `getABC`.

---

### Your use case

In your case, you want to set the font depending on the preference. You could store the font in `sp` (i.e. use it in the settings page). Then, in your layouts, you could set the font size of `TextView`s programatically.

I think to be honest, it may not be worth the effort - the code can get quite messy as well if you're having to set font sizes of lots of `TextView`s programatically. The Android OS already has a settings option that users can use to increase or decrease the font size on all of their apps, so I would advise against it.

However, trying to implement it will help you learn more about Android and if you have a strong reason for having that settings option, then that's fine too. ;)

**Edit: Settings option**

As I mentioned, the Android OS has an option for changing font size. They're available in:

> Settings > Display > Font size

If I remember correctly, newer versions of Android also have the option for changing display size, which scales the size of items on the screen, not just fonts.

Comment: Thank you a thousand times, that means a lot. You have made the creation of the settings part crystal clear. Here is my problem, lets say we have a list preferance which should make the user able to pick a font size. How do we code to make this happen?

Comment: Oh and to add on I know this has something to do with onPreferenceChangedListener but I still dont know how to code this and in which activity the code should be.

Comment: No problem - glad I could help. I've updated my answer to include more information on `OnPreferenceChangeListener` and reading the preferences programatically.

Comment: Quoting "The Android OS already has a settings option that users can use to increase or decrease the font size..." This sounds great because what I want to archive is to set font size from a list of choices. I would be greatful if you can show me how to do that.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the stuff on the settings option.

Comment: Ok I see. The Project iam working on is a hym book. So on huge smart phones and tablets, the default text size for text views will be small compared to the screen size of the device so I wanted to give users an option to increase text view text size/font as per their device.

Comment: So thats where iam stuck right now on my project. The need to make users customise the text views text size.

Comment: @D.Freeman You may find it's more useful to provide [alternate resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) depending on the device type. For example, on tablets, the font size could be larger than on smartphones. You can read more about that if you're interested at the link.